# Can't maximize window using Selenium

Tags: selenium, window, maximize

I'm trying to maximize my browser window using the following code:

```
driver.manage().window().maximize();
```

But then, I get the following exception:

`[31mcucumber.runtime.CucumberException: Failed to instantiate class mapfre.automationTestsMcc.steps.mcs.ChangeIP
        at cucumber.runtime.java.DefaultJavaObjectFactory.cacheNewInstance(DefaultJavaObjectFactory.java:40)
        at cucumber.runtime.java.DefaultJavaObjectFactory.getInstance(DefaultJavaObjectFactory.java:26)
        at cucumber.runtime.java.JavaStepDefinition.execute(JavaStepDefinition.java:35)
        at cucumber.runtime.StepDefinitionMatch.runStep(StepDefinitionMatch.java:37)`

Any Idea why I'm getting this?

Comment: You get an exception before that point. Check the issue related to Cucumber first.

Comment: The issue should be related to that point because, when I comment that line, everything works fine.